# What is the correct way to completely remove GoogleMaps Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I use GoogleMap v3 [AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#Autocomplete) and I need to completely remove it and unbind all event listeners. My code for initializing and binding to events looks like the following:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("input").get(0), {
   types: ["geocode"]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
  // handle events
});
```

I don't find official way to correctly remove autocomplete and unbind all events. Please point me the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the unbinding of events use [`google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event).

For removing of the autocomplete-functionality there is no implemented method.
You may create a clone of the input before you create the Automplete and when you want to remove the autocomplete-functionality replace the current input with  the clone.

```js
//--------------------------------------------------------------
      //this overides the built-in Autocomplete and adds a remove-listener
      //execute it once when the API has been loaded
     (function(ac) {
         google.maps.places.Autocomplete = function(node, opts) {
           var clone = node.cloneNode(true),
             pac = new ac(node, opts);

           google.maps.event
             .addListener(pac,
               'remove',
               function(restore) {
                   google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(pac);
                   google.maps.event.trigger(node,'blur');
                   google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(node);
                 if (restore===true) {
                   node.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, node);
                 } else {
                   node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
                 }
               });
           return pac;

         }
       }
       (google.maps.places.Autocomplete));
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

     function initialize() {

       autocomplete = new google.maps.places
         .Autocomplete(document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0], {
           types: ["geocode"]
         });
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&.js"></script>
<input/>
<span>
  <input  type="button"  value="remove input" 
          onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(window.autocomplete,'remove');
                   this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"/>
  <input  type="button"  value="remove autocomplete-functionality" 
          onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(window.autocomplete,'remove',true);
                   this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"/>
<span>
```

The script adds a remove-listener to Automplete's. 
The listener accepts a single argument. Set it to `true` when you only want to remove the autocomplete-functionality. Otherwise the input will be removed completely.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. Please could explain what is the difference in following methods: `clearInstanceListeners`, `clearListeners` and `removeListener`. Should I use all of them or I using of `clearInstanceListeners` is enough?

Comment: `removeListener` removes a particular listener, `clearListeners` removes all listeners for a particular event from a given  object, `clearInstanceListeners` removes all listeners(regardless of the event-type) from a given object.  It's sufficient to use `clearInstanceListeners`